# First argument of bash is different when parameter is passed or not

Tags: bash

There are two `bash` usages:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $0'
bash

$bash -c 'echo $0' "text"
text
```

Why in the first case parameter `$0` holds the program name but in second the first parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the `bash` man page:

> ```
>    -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from  the
>              first non-option argument command_string.  If there are argu‐
>              ments after the command_string,  they  are  assigned  to  the
>              positional parameters, starting with $0.
> ```

And further down:

> ```
>    If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor the
>    -s option has been supplied, the first argument is assumed  to  be  the
>    name  of  a file containing shell commands.  If bash is invoked in this
>    fashion, $0 is set to the name of the file, and the positional  parame‐
>    ters  are set to the remaining arguments.
> ```

In short, `$0`'s behaviour varies depending on how bash is invoked.